# how to use a categorical variable to control pch value in plot

Tags: r, plot

I find that I need to use a function to control what character is used in a scatter plot instead of just passing in a categorical variable.  Why is that?

Here's what I have tried.

Here is what the input file looks like

```
~/data $ head avgpm25.csv
"pm25","fips","region","longitude","latitude"
9.77118522614686,"01003","east",-87.74826,30.592781
9.99381725284814,"01027","east",-85.842858,33.26581
10.6886181012839,"01033","east",-87.72596,34.73148
11.3374236874237,"01049","east",-85.798919,34.459133
12.1197644686119,"01055","east",-86.032125,34.018597
10.8278048723489,"01069","east",-85.350387,31.189731
11.5839280137523,"01073","east",-86.82805,33.527872
11.2619958748527,"01089","east",-86.588226,34.73079
9.41442269955754,"01097","east",-88.139667,30.722256
```

here is a transcript of R session

```
> pollution <- fread("~/Downloads/data//avgpm25.csv")
> str(pollution)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  576 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ pm25     : num  9.77 9.99 10.69 11.34 12.12 ...
 $ fips     : chr  "01003" "01027" "01033" "01049" ...
 $ region   : chr  "east" "east" "east" "east" ...
 $ longitude: num  -87.7 -85.8 -87.7 -85.8 -86 ...
 $ latitude : num  30.6 33.3 34.7 34.5 34 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

notice that `pollution$region` is `chr`

```
> with(pollution, plot(pm25))  # this works, but all points are black
> with(pollution, plot(pm25, col = region)) # this fails
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name 'east'
> with(pollution, plot(pm25, col = as.factor(region))) # this works, points of two region get painted in two different colors
```

And here is the reason for my question.  Why doesn't this work

```
> with(pollution, plot(pm25, col = as.factor(region), pch = as.factor(region)))
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plotting symbol
```

but defining a function and then passing it in works!

```
> pch_func <- function(x) { ifelse (x == "east", 1, 2)}
> with(pollution, plot(pm25, col = as.factor(region), pch = pch_func(region)))
```

Neither does this work

```
> pollution <- mutate(pollution, region = as.factor(region))
> with(pollution, plot(pm25, col = region, pch = region))
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plotting symbol
```

Why is this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can do `with(pollution, plot(pm25, pch=region))`

Answer (score 1):

From `?par`

> **pch** Either an integer specifying a symbol or a single character to be
>   used as the default in plotting points. See points for possible values
>   and their interpreta

So you should convert yourfactorto `integer`:

```
 with(pollution, plot(pm25, col = as.factor(region), 
            pch = as.integer(region)))
```

### Example with data :

[image]

```
dx<- read.table(text='pm25,fips,region,longitude,latitude
                9.77118522614686,01003,east,-87.74826,30.592781
                9.99381725284814,01027,east,-85.842858,33.26581
                10.6886181012839,01033,east,-87.72596,34.73148
                11.3374236874237,01049,east,-85.798919,34.459133
                12.1197644686119,01055,aaa,-86.032125,34.018597
                10.8278048723489,01069,east,-85.350387,31.189731
                11.5839280137523,01073,aaaa,-86.82805,33.527872
                11.2619958748527,01089,east,-86.588226,34.73079
                9.41442269955754,01097,aaaa,-88.139667,30.722256',header=TRUE,sep=',')


with(dx, plot(pm25, col = as.factor(region), pch = as.integer(region)))
```

Comment: but why doesn't `pch` treat factors like `col`?

Comment: @nongkrong colors are different since you can specify them as characters "red" blue or in hexadecimal ...I guess that when you give it a factor it is coerced to its HEX representation. This give you a different color but you don't control anything.

Comment: thanks, +1, but still doesn't it seem strange that `pch` has no default to deal with factors since their underlying representation is integer?  I was going to try to look at its code, but couldn't see where to look...

Comment: good luck! I don't know why you want things that works in base R. It is a real waste of time ( there are many things to learn in R and with a deep learning curve). Besides the fact that there are more higher level graphics libraries in R that deal well with factors.